# Assign similar colors to same-class variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset similar to below, where each class has two different instances within it. Ideally, I would like to assign consistent and similar colors to each instance within a class. Is it possible to do this automatically or should I manually assign the colors?

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(class = rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=2),
                  instance = 1:6,
                  values = rnorm(6))

ggplot(dat, aes(instance, values)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=class))
```

For example, since both `1` and `2` are in class `A`, the colors for each instance should be similar. To clarify, the colors should be similar but not identical, so that you can still tell there are two different instances.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be to adjust the alpha between instances within each class:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(class = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=2),
                  instance = 1:6,
                  values = rnorm(6))

ggplot(dat, aes(instance, values)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = class),
             alpha = rep(c(1, 0.5), nrow(dat)/2))
```

This gives us:

[image]

Comment: That's really interesting. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one solution would be create a customized palette of colors and then assign according the unique number of classes and instances. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
dat <- data.frame(class = rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=2),
                  instance = 1:6,
                  values = rnorm(6))
#Color for plot
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "red"))
#Plot
ggplot(dat, aes(factor(instance), values,fill=factor(instance),group=factor(instance))) +
  geom_point(aes(color=class),shape=21)+
  scale_color_manual(values=colfunc(length(unique(dat$class))))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colfunc(length(unique(dat$instance))))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The colors for each instance in a class look identical in the plot above. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough: The colors should be similar but not identical, so that you can still tell there are two different instances.

Comment: @Adam_G Hi. I have added a new possible solution. I hope that can be helpful!

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting idea to use a different color for the fill and the outline. If no one posts another idea, I may go with it.

Comment: @Adam_G I hope that could help on your issue :)